# Type Inference in Extension Method

Tags: .net, nullable

I'm sure this has been asked before, but my perusal of the search hits for similar questions did not yield an answer.

I am tired of checking if Nullable has a value.  Why can't I assign `myNullable<int> yourAge` to `int myAge` and get an exception if  `yourAge` is null?  Furthermore, if either of our damned ages is null, why do I have to do a fxning check to avoid assigning 'deafault' to a fxning SqlParameter?  I can't even do a civilised `mySqlParm = myAge.HasValue ? myAge.Value : DBNull.Value`.

What is the fxning point of nullable types?  We still have to use `-1' for a pkId to avoid the dreaded Null.  We can't even add our own extension menthods because 'blah blah'.

Why even fxning bother with parameters at all?  Why don't we just store all dates as fxning varchar(10)?

Comment: What's your question?  What does Nullable<T> have to do with the database?

Comment: maybe "type inference in an extension method" is what inspired you to write this, but it's not the right title for this post as is.

Comment: Yes, @Walt W, I was angry and not for no reason.

Comment: @nader, I will assume from your comment that you have precious little experience interfacing .NET code with a SQL Server database.  I hope for your part that one day you will gain the experience, the lack of prompted, my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can't I assign `myNullable<int>`
>   `yourAge` to `int myAge` and get an
>   exception if `yourAge` is null?

Of course you can. Just use the Value property without checking first:

```
int myAge = yourAge.Value;
```

If `yourAge` contains null you will get an exception.

Comment: Thanks @Guffa, never occurred to me, being blinded by other complexities.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you want to do something like this?

```
public static object GetDatabaseValueFromNullableType<T>(this T? value) 
    where T: struct
{
    return value.HasValue ? (object) value.Value : DBNull.Value;
}
```

and then you can use it like so:

```
//this is just a test I wrote but you get the idea
[Test]
public void NullableTest()
{
    int? something = null;
    var value = something.GetDatabaseValueFromNullableType();
    Assert.IsTrue(value == DBNull.Value);
}
```

Comment: +1 for the test based example.  You deserve a bounty, but I can only do that on my next question.  Stay tuned. :-)